# Had any Spanish words been established in Russian by 1800?

Tags: история-языка, заимствования

I started wondering about long-established loanwords from the Spanish language. It's easy to find some lists of same, but not with dates of attribution. Here's a [great list](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F:%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/ru) from Wiktionary.

Had any Spanish words had been adopted into Russian before 1800? I wouldn't be too surprised if not; the majority appear to be more recent.

Comment: Aaron, your question is basically about a list of words, it usually does not work well as a question. Please, try to google "слова испанского происхождения в русском языке"

Comment: @shabunc Thank you. I rephrased it more directly about the date of interest. I believe that there are few-to-no such words.

Comment: question like "is word X of Spanish origin is on-topic", question like "what words ere adopted before 19th century" is too broad - however in your particular case the answer is a very short list-  Spanish woth not a major source of borrowing in Russian - http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/leksikologia/slovo-proishozhdenie/zaimstvovaniya-v-russkom-yazike-iz-ispanskogo-yazika/1219/?q=463&n=1219 - 

also it's still not clear - have you tried to google? If yes -  what exactly was missing?

Comment: @shabunc I don't have a source for the dates the words entered Russian.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5#%D0%98%D0%B7_%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: @shabunc If you can, please suggest a resource that would allow me to answer the question, or a way to reframe it while staying on-topic.

Comment: the answer to your question the way it is put is "yes", _гитара_ being one example. It does not make an interesting answer, though, and asking for a list of all those words is off topic, I'm afraid. A better question I think would be how did it happen that Spanish and not some other language words end up meaning what they mean in Russian, and what are the lexical strata we should be looking in for these words.